# Elementary Number Theory - David Burton - solutions

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Does anybody know where I can find the solutions of the exercises from CH12 & CH13 & CH14 from David Burton's Elementary Number Theory (7th edition) on the internet for free?

Comment: There are some links given, e.g., [here](http://www.americanriver.com/mathematics/elementary_number_theory.html). Did you already search?

Comment: Yeah, but there are no chapters I need

Comment: Which means, you have to search more than just this link.